# In chromium, Does the Browser process paints the web page or the renderer process?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

In https://seclab.stanford.edu/websec/chromium/chromium-security-architecture.pdf, it mentions in page 4 , left column, under **browser kernel** section that

> The browser kernel is responsible for displaying JavaScript alert
>   dialog boxes, whereas `<select>` drop-down menus are displayed by the
>   rendering engine.

I am not clear with what process is responsible for actually rendering and displaying of a web page. Displaying as in w.r.t OS native window manager.

Which process actually paints the web page, the renderer process or the bowser kernel, into the UI?